# Stochastic/sequential gradient descent for the perceptron

Tags: multivariable-calculus, machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I'll quote Bishop's [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://link.springer.com/book/9780387310732) (2006) in the context of the perceptron, an algorithm that, given two finite subsets of "patterns" $\mathcal{C}_1,\mathcal{C}_2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^D$, finds a hyperplane parametrized by $y(\mathbf{x}):=\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+w_0=0$ that separates $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$ (when possible):

> [...] The perceptron criterion [error function to be minimized] is therefore given by
> \begin{equation}\tag{4.54}
> E_P(\mathbf{w}) = -\sum_{n\in\mathcal{M}}\mathbf{w}^T\phi_n t_n
> \end{equation}
> where $\mathcal{M}$ denotes the set of misclassified patterns. [...] We now apply the stochastic [or sequential] gradient descent algorithm to this error function. The change in weight [$\mathbf{w}$] is then given by
> \begin{equation}\tag{4.55}
> \mathbf{w}^{(\tau +1)}=\mathbf{w}^\tau - \eta\nabla E_P(\mathbf{w})=\mathbf{w}^\tau +\eta\phi_n t_n
> \end{equation}
> where $\eta$ is the learning rate parameter and $\tau$ is an integer that indexes the step of the algorithm. [...] Note that, as the weight vector evolves during training, the set of patterns that are missclassified will change.

How does $\nabla E_P(\mathbf{w}) = -\phi_n t_n$?

As Bishop mentions, $\mathcal{M}$ depends on the choice of $\mathbf{w}$ so the gradient doesn't commute with $\sum_{n\in \mathcal{M}}$. Furthermore, what does $n$ mean in this context? $n$, in the sum that defines $E_P(\mathbf{w})$, takes the role of an indexation variable so I don't see how one could then use it outside of the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation 4.55 is very misleading. The paragraph after your excerpt does a better job of explaining the author's intent.

> The perceptron learning algorithm has a simple interpretation, as follows. We cycle through the training patterns in turn, and for each pattern $x_n$ we evaluate the perceptron function (4.52). If the pattern is correctly classified, then the weight vector remains unchanged, whereas if it is incorrectly classified, then for class $\mathcal{C}_1$ we add the vector $\phi(x_n)$ onto the current estimate of weight vector $\mathbf{w}$ while for class $\mathcal{C}_2$ we subtract the vector $\phi(x_n)$ from $\mathbf{w}$.

In stochastic gradient descent, instead of using the gradient of the entire error function, you choose one of the data points $x_n$ evaluate the gradient of the individual addend of the error function corresponding to that data point. For your $E_P$ function, this becomes
$$\begin{cases}0 & n \notin \mathcal{M} \\ -\phi_n t_n & n \in \mathcal{M}\end{cases}$$

So the update is essentially $\mathbf{w}^{\tau + 1} \gets \mathbf{w} - \eta \phi_n t_n \mathbf{1}_{n \in \mathcal{M}}$, which matches the plain English description above.

Equation 4.55 is misleading in two ways: (1) it suggests that it is using the full gradient $\nabla E_P$ as the step, when it is actually using the stochastic gradient method, and (2) it only applies for the case when $n \in \mathcal{M}$.

Comment: When you say "$\mathbf{w}^{\tau +1} \gets \mathbf{w}-\eta\phi_n t_n \mathbf{1}_{n\in\mathcal{M}}$", which $n$ are you referring to? Any random $n$ ?

Comment: In stochastic gradient descent, you choose a data point $x_n$ from your dataset at random (or iterate through them in order). Choosing that point determines the $n$ you will use for the update. @SebastiánP.Pincheira